# Immediately Invoked Functions as Property Assignment in objects.

Tags: javascript

While going through the types of function we can write, I thought of this type of function. 
I was referring this link :
https://www.bryanbraun.com/2014/11/27/every-possible-way-to-define-a-javascript-function/

I combined the Immediately Invoked and Property Assignment types and its working. 
Can you guys please help me in correcting me if I am wrong.

Here is the code snippet with the output i console.

```
var obj = {
  sum : (function(num1, num2){
    console.log(num1 +  num2);
  })(1,2)
}

var obj2 = {
  sum : (function add(num1, num2){
  console.log(num1+num2);
})(2,3)
}
```

Console Output :

```
//3
//5
```

Comment: "*… and its working*" - so what is your question?

Comment: I just want to know what is the basic difference?

Comment: The only difference between the two assignments is their inconsistent whitespacing and the arguments that you are passing.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are missing the `return` statement - currently their return value is `undefined` hence the object keys also hold undefined value.